# Posting a codepen.io website on github pages

Tags: html, github, github-pages, codepen

I recently started doing the courses on free code camp and finished the first project of building a tribute page on codepen.io

Now I've been trying to show the finished website on GitHub using GitHub pages but whatever i do the site does not show up.

I've tried upload the repo and adding pages in the settings but it only shows the read me when i visit the GitHub page link.

Any help on setting this up will be appreciated!
...

...
my codepen project: https://codepen.io/ra-y9/pen/mdVvREb

Comment: Can you share the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure of the following:

1. The file is named index.html
2. The file is in the master branch(and not in any other branch you created).
3. You have to make sure that the "None" in Source(mentioned in the image below) has been changed to "master branch".[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer.It seems that there was an issue with pages yesterday.It is working as intended now and my page is up and running.